# Flex container width when flex-flow is set to column wrap

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have container with fixed height and `display: flex`. I want it's children to be laid in a column-first manner by setting `-webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wNtqF/1/

1. Can anyone explain me how chrome calculates the resulting width of the container div (div with green border) and why is leaves so much free space on the right of each red item. What I want is to have the container to have width just to fit all children, without the additional empty space.
2. If it's not possible with pure css can you provide me an alternative to achive this?

I'm using Chrome `v 29.0.1547.76`

The code to reproduce it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .flex-container {
        position: fixed;
        height: 90%;

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        border: 6px solid green;

        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;

        -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start
    }


    /** Just to show the elements */
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .flex-item {
        background: tomato;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 10px;

        line-height: 150px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="flex-container">
        <li class="flex-item">1</li>
        <li class="flex-item">2</li>
        <li class="flex-item">3</li>
        <li class="flex-item">4</li>
        <li class="flex-item">5</li>
        <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: If you change the direction between row and column, you'll see that the width of the flex container does not change.  This can't be done with pure CSS.  Using columns is the next best thing, but it doesn't seem to give the effect you're looking for.

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome and Firefox. and still there.

Comment: Downvoted - you should add a minimal-as-possible example to your question, not only a Fiddle-link. So is an expected behaviour missing. (I assume your intent was to make the green bordered box so wide that all items fit into the box but as small to tightly wrap the item). Note that Flexbox can't change the containers size while trying to lay out items within that container according to the width/height constraints. [See the Flexbox layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm). A possible fix would be to give the container a `width: 220px`.

Comment: @try-catch-finally i added the code. I hope your "minimal-as-possible example" needs are satisfied now.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome automatically puts the space between the div and the border top, to fix this, you can just use:

> margin-bottom: 100%;

Why this? margin-bottom: 100% reset the element and move the item up.
You've tried with:

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But this didn't work because body sposte the page html and not single element.

The complete code will are here:

```css
.flex-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: 6px solid green;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start
}


/** Just to show the elements */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100%;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This does not help. The asker did not understand that flexbox needs a definite container size to correctly lay out the items in a container. Flexbox can't layout items within a container and adapt the container itself at the same time.